# Python SQL: storing objects or iterables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, blob, pickle

Assume I want to store via sqlite3 a simple list of strings:

```
my_list = ['a','b','c']
```

or a python object with properties and methods.

What I tried so far is to serialize (pickle) `my_list`, and the returned byte representation is `b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02X\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x03e.'`. However, `\` cannot be stored within a BLOB variable.

Should I use a string variable instead, or should I find a way to convert the serialized object into a different format to get rid of the `\` before storing?

Note that I'm learning SQL and the fundamentals of data conversion.

Comment: The `\ ` are not part of the byte string; they're introduced when you print it out

Comment: Also, a blob can definitely store `\ `; if you're having trouble, you're probably missing the use of placeholders and parameters when running your SQL statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into how to serialize the data.
Storing complex objects into a relational database (sqlite) is not easy.
I suggest saving the data as a json string or perhaps in a JSONField.

May I ask, how are you accessing the sqlite? (eg. sqlite module, via django models, flask or other)

You can take this code as a reference (I am using sqlite3 module).
It think you might have missed `sqlite3.Binary(binary_obj)`

```
import sqlite3
import sqlite3
import pickle


def store_in_db(obj):
    binary_obj = pickle.dumps(obj)
    print('binary_obj: ', binary_obj)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('demo.db')
    conn.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (binary_field BLOB)')
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES(?)', [sqlite3.Binary(binary_obj)])
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def retrieve_from_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('demo.db')
    row = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM DemoTable').fetchone()
    obj = pickle.loads(row[0])
    conn.close()

    return obj


my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
store_in_db(my_list)

print(retrieve_from_db())
```

Comment: What is the purpose of  calling `sqlite3.Binary`?  `bytes` instances can be saved directly.